# onPressed action On Custom Leading Images Appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

Is it possible we can add `onPressed` action on the logo and start another activity?

I am creating a simple flutter app where I have used `AppBar` and in leading icon I have used a custom logo. I am not sure how to perform `onPressed` method so that it starts another activity. Anyone please help me here. Below is my app bar code.

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/logo.png",
          ),
        ),
        title: Text('Safe Outs Business'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Admin HomePage'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Click here to see a sample Image of the layout I am trying to build in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzcQJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your logo inside a `GestureDetector`:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => print('TAPPED!'),
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/logo.png",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    title: Text('Safe Outs Business'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Text('Admin HomePage'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much @Thierry it worked i added this also
   ``` Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
              );```